# calculating mean for every n values from a vector

Tags: r, vector, mean

So lets say I have a vector

```
a <- rnorm(6000)
```

I want to calculate the mean of the 1st value to the 60th, then again calculate the mean for the 61st value to the 120th and so fourth. So basically I want to calculate the mean for every 60th values giving me 100 means from that vector. I know I can do a for loop but I'd like to know if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: You might be glad giving a look at [apply()](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family#gs.kcIGiwE) function

Comment: apply function is mostly good for data frames/matrices. I am asking about a vector here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use

```
 colMeans(matrix(a, 60))
.colMeans(a, 60, length(a) / 60)  # more efficient (without reshaping to matrix)
```

---

**Enhancement on user [adunaic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4095502/adunaic)'s request**

> This only works if there are 60x100 data points. If you have an incomplete 60 at the end then this errors. It would be good to have a general solution for others looking at this problem for ideas.

```
BinMean <- function (vec, every, na.rm = FALSE) {
  n <- length(vec)
  x <- .colMeans(vec, every, n %/% every, na.rm)
  r <- n %% every
  if (r) x <- c(x, mean.default(vec[(n - r + 1):n], na.rm = na.rm))
  x
  }

a <- 1:103
BinMean(a, every = 10)
# [1]   5.5  15.5  25.5  35.5  45.5  55.5  65.5  75.5  85.5  95.5 102.0
```

---

**Alternative solution with group-by operation (less efficient)**

```
BinMean2 <- function (vec, every, na.rm = FALSE) {
  grp <- as.integer(ceiling(seq_along(vec) / every))
  grp <- structure(grp, class = "factor",
                   levels = as.character(seq_len(grp[length(grp)])) )
  lst <- .Internal(split(vec, grp))
  unlist(lapply(lst, mean.default, na.rm = na.rm), use.names = FALSE)
  }
```

---

**Speed**

```
library(microbenchmark)
a <- runif(1e+4)
microbenchmark(BinMean(a, 100), BinMean2(a, 100))
#Unit: microseconds
#             expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq       max
#  BinMean(a, 100)   40.400   42.1095   54.21286   48.3915   57.6555   205.702
# BinMean2(a, 100) 1216.823 1335.7920 1758.90267 1434.9090 1563.1535 21467.542
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend `sapply`:

```
a <- rnorm(6000)
seq <- seq(1, length(a), 60)
a_mean <- sapply(seq, function(i) {mean(a[i:(i+59)])})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `tapply` by creating a grouping variable.

Grouping variable could be created in two ways :

**1) Using `rep`**

```
tapply(a, rep(seq_along(a), each = n, length.out = length(a)), mean)
```

**2) Using `gl`**

```
tapply(a, gl(length(a)/n, n), mean)
```

---

If we convert the vector to dataframe/tibble we can use the same logic and calculate the `mean`

```
aggregate(a~gl(length(a)/n, n), data.frame(a), mean)
```

OR with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

tibble::tibble(a) %>%
          group_by(group = gl(length(a)/n, n)) %>%
          summarise(mean_val = mean(a))
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
a <- rnorm(6000)
n <- 60
```