# Calculate mean of every nth element

Tags: r

I have a vector that holds hourly data of 31 days, so it has a length of 31*24 = 744. Now I would like to calculate the mean diurnal cycle of the variable that is included in the vector. In order to do that, the mean value of every hour of the day is needed. For 01 UTC for example, the relevant steps are `1,25,49,73,...,721`, for 2 UTC they are `2,26,50,74,...,722` and so forth. So I need something that enables the calculation of the mean value with a 24 element moving window.

Here is some code for an exemplary vector:

```
set.seed(1)
my.vec <- sample(-20:20, size = 744, replace = T)
```

The output vector should then be of length `24`, of course.

Anybody with a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution, using base R:

```r
rowMeans(matrix(my.vec, 24, 31))

#>  [1] -0.9354839 -0.3548387 -1.0322581  2.5161290  2.1290323  0.7419355
#>  [7]  1.3870968  1.4838710  0.9032258 -1.9032258  4.2903226 -0.4193548
#> [13] -1.9354839 -3.1935484 -2.1935484  2.0322581  0.2580645  2.4193548
#> [19]  0.8064516  0.8064516  5.0645161 -0.5806452 -1.2580645 -0.1290323
```

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewGB, for having commented my answer! I did not know about `.rowMeans` at all. So that is good to learn it!

Comment: You can also write it as `.rowMeans(my.vec, 24, 31)` so that you don't have to convert to a matrix first. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43635971/15293191 for more information.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rollapply` and it should also work with vectors of different lengths

```
library(zoo)
out <- colMeans(rollapply(seq_along(my.vec), width = 24, by = 24,
     FUN = function(i) my.vec[i]))
```

-checking

```
> length(out)
[1] 24
> mean(my.vec[seq(1, length(my.vec), by = 24)])
[1] -0.9354839
> mean(my.vec[seq(2, length(my.vec), by = 24)])
[1] -0.3548387
> out[1:2]
[1] -0.9354839 -0.3548387
```

Answer (score 2):

**base**

```r
set.seed(1)
my.vec <- sample(-20:20, size = 744, replace = T)
m <- matrix(my.vec, 31, byrow = TRUE)
colMeans(m)
#>  [1] -0.9354839 -0.3548387 -1.0322581  2.5161290  2.1290323  0.7419355
#>  [7]  1.3870968  1.4838710  0.9032258 -1.9032258  4.2903226 -0.4193548
#> [13] -1.9354839 -3.1935484 -2.1935484  2.0322581  0.2580645  2.4193548
#> [19]  0.8064516  0.8064516  5.0645161 -0.5806452 -1.2580645 -0.1290323
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this does the job too. The solution above from PaulS is just simpler as it is a oneliner.